# How to increase TeX memory for LaTeX in TeX Live on Windows?

Tags: installing, texlive, windows, memory

How to increase TeX memory for (pdf)LaTeX in TeX Live on windows (7)? I found a lot of usefull instructions to increase the TeX memory on linux systems or with MikTeX on Windows, but I still miss a recipe as a kind of step by step instruction for the procedure in TeX Live under Windows.

Comment: Exactly why do you need to increase the memory in the first place?

Comment: I need to increase the memory to handle big datasets in pgfplots. In the pgfplots manual are good instructions for MikTeX/Windows and Linux/Unix/TeX Live.

Comment: You can create your own `texmf.cnf` file as described in `pgfplots` manual for windows too.